# Ubuntu "Running on low graphic mode"!Hit Restart! Stuck at loading for hours!

Tags: ubuntu

On boot it says "Running on low graphic mode" and give option, clicked on Restart X but still stuck at loading screen for hours! What should be done to repair? (it's on dual boot with Windows 7)

Comment: How did you get to this point? Did you just install the O/S, or did you perform some kind of H/W change, or was this sponaneous? Also, what version of Ubuntu (and therefore xorg) are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I got to this point after I played around with empathy's libraries. It was running on dual boot with Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting X won't do anything unless you've made changes to the config. I suggest you just boot in low graphics, and install the correct driver. You haven't stated which graphics chipset you're using.

This thread will be moved to Superuser.com but follow it up. Post more detail. And try asking people in IRC (irc.freenode.net #ubuntu).

Comment: I'm using ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4500 Series. btw, how to make changes to the config? i'm new to Ubuntu.